# Display Custom UIView On Top of UIViewController

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I'm looking for opinions on the best way to implement the following functionality. I have a UIViewController with a UITableView in Grouped Format. Each TableViewCell contains an NSString. When the User taps on a cell I'd like to in my didSelectRowForIndexPath method popup a UIView with a single textfield, that's prepopulated with the NSString in the given cell that was selected. The reason for displaying the UIVIew is I want it to be about 280 x 380 frame and still see some of the UITableView.

The goal being that it behaves like a ModalViewController except for the iPhone. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to implement this behavior or if there is a better implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the UIView (with the UITextField inside) beforehand, and make it hidden:

```
// Of course, these instance variable names are made up, and should be changed
self.myModalView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 280, 380)] autorelease];
[self.view addSubview:self.myModalView]

self.myTextField = [[[UITextField alloc] init] autorelease];
[self.myModalView addSubview:self.myTextField];

self.myModalView.hidden = YES;
```

Then, when the user selects a row, populate the text field and show the modal view:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
  // Replace stringAtIndexPath with however your data source accesses the string
  NSString* myString = [self stringAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  self.myTextField.text = myString;
  self.myModalView.hidden = NO;
}
```

If you want to get fancy, you can do some CATransition stuff before showing the modal view.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use "addSubView" in UITableView. Add the ModalView to your UITableView directly. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

Use some animation to implement this effect. When the UIView appears, it will lift the UITableView, like some keyboard behavior. So, you have to addSubView on the self.view and modify the UITableView's frame. And, the UITableView should be a child view of self.view, if self.view is the same as the UITableView, then you has no self.view for adding this UIView.